# error: expected identifier before numeric constant Issue Once Again

Tags: c++, object, constants, numeric, identifier

Team,
This question has been asked many times, but the answers don't seem to fit my situation. Here's my VERY simple code. The line of code that is causing the problem works perfectly in the main routine; however, when I try to embed an object within an object using the exact same code the error message shows up. I suspect the cause is silly, but I'm too close and can't see it...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDnfK.jpg)

Comment: There are no teams here. Furthermore, I do not see a valid question here, either.

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question as text.

Comment: You can't initialize a member variable this way. Ironically, since C++11 you can write `A one = 100.0`. but you should check your textbook/tutorial for description of classes and constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Within a class you have to use the member-initialization list to initialize your member variable `A` in `B`:

```
class B{
public:
    A one; //Declare one here
    int numbluemarbles;
    B(): one(100){} //initialize one here
};
```

In c++11 or newer you can also use the newer syntax:

```
class B{
public:
    A one = 100.0; //C++11
    int numbluemarbles;
};
```

For more about how you can use c++11 initialization options have a read of this: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519

Comment: You make it sound like this C++11 initialization was lost in C++14 (the current C++.) That's besides answering an off-topic question.

Comment: shuttle87: Fantastic answer -- thank you very much. I must confess that I had gotten this far in my C++ adventure and had never encountered member-initialization lists before. I really appreciate you sharing this with me -- clearly I've got more learning to do!!!